# When removing jquery ui tab programatically, can I renumber the remaining ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding and removing jquery tabs programatically, with:

```
function addtab(input) {
     var num_tabs = $("div#tabs ul li").length + 1;
     $("div#tabs ul").append(
     "<li class='test' title = '" + input + "'><a href='#tab" + num_tabs + "'>" + input + "</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'></span></li>"
     );
     $("div#tabs").append(
          "<img id='tab" + num_tabs + "' src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Viewer_2D'; height='100%' width='100%'/>"
     );
     $("div#tabs").tabs("option", "active", num_tabs-1);
     $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
}

$(function() {
     $("#tabs").on( "click", "span.ui-icon-close", function() {
          var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
          $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
          tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
     });
});
```

If I add three tabs, and then remove the last tab, there is no problem when trying to add an additional tab- the id of the new tab will be 'num_tabs'.  However, if I were to add three tabs, and then remove the first tab, then the tab with id=num_tabs already exists.  How can I handle this?  Can I renumber the tab ids after removing tabs?

Comment: Please make a link to codepen with full code in order me to replicate and make a solution for you. I already have an idea to solve it.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't used codepen before, but this is the link to the html; https://codepen.io/ajkrueger/pen/KKvxdOq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention this in your question, but I assume there isn't a need for the ID's to be sequential. What matters is that each ID is unique.

Instead of using `num_tabs` to determine the number of the tab, you could simply always increment the number (do **not** decrement it when deleting tabs).

This can be done in multiple ways, like...

- Use a variable that keeps track of how many tabs you've added.
- Use jQuery's `data-` syntax (see [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the number of the tab as a value on the tab. By doing this, you can retrieve the number on the last tab and increment it to determine the number of the next tab.
- Parse the id of the last-tab using a regex expression to retrieve the numeric value and increment that number when adding a new tab.